# How to set maximum possible length to string column using hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate

I am using :

```
@Length(max = 300)
private String data;
```

for setting the length of variable data. How can I set the maximum possible length?

I am unsure what to Google for.

Thanks for your help.

Edit: or what type of column is best to use for very long string,.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use varchar for your column use this to limit the lenght.

```
@Column(length = 300)
```

For 300 characters you should be ok with varchar.

For a very long string you may consider TEXT for the column type.